# How to upload a Windows Forms Application to a Web Page?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a Windows Forms Application on Visual Studio with multiple forms that link together via button clicks. It also has a connection to an SQL Server which is used to store data that is entered into the textboxes and other controls.

Is there any possible way to host this application onto a Web Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If you want to make the functionality available on the web you will have to rewrite the application as a web application.

You can use VB.net to code a web application so you would be able to reuse *some* of your existing code.

Comment: @Joabdh100 Yes you can use VB.net to code a web application.